# Is there any way to hide page from dashboard (all pages list) OR navbar from plugin function?

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying to include a template from plugin which required to display some of my custom information's. I wrote function to insert a page and included the template. It's working for me but once i created the page it automatically displaying in navbar menu list(currently using thwentythirteen theme).

So actually i don't want to display my custom page from NAVBAR (menu-list) as well as from Dashboard all pages list (if possible) too. There is any way to get over from this situations ?

Here is my code:

```
function create_user_content_page() {

$post_id = -1;

// Setup custom vars
$author_id = 1;
$slug = 'user-data-content';
$title = 'Data Content';

// Check if page exists, if not create it
if ( null == get_page_by_title( $title )) {

    $dataContent_page = array(
            'comment_status'   => 'closed',
            'ping_status'      => 'closed',
            'post_author'      => $author_id,
            'post_name'        => $slug,
            'post_title'       => $title,
            'post_status'      => 'private',
            'post_type'        => 'page'
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $dataContent_page );


    if ( !$post_id ) {

            wp_die( 'Error creating template page' );

    } else {

            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'content-template.php' );

    }
  } // end check if

}


add_action( 'template_include', 'content_template' );

function content_template( $template ) {
global $post;


 if ($post->post_type == 'user-data-content')  {

    $template = dirname( __FILE__ ). '/content-template.php';
  }
  return $template;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not completely understand what you are doing, but I get the feeling that you have greatly over-complicate this. You don't have to create a "Page" at all to load a custom template. You can hook to `template_include` and simply include a plugin file with much less effort than you are currently going through.

For example [(stolen form another answer)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124971/21376):

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'portfolio_newpage_template', 99 );
function portfolio_newpage_template( $template ) {  
  get_header();
  include('/some/file/path/file.php');
  get_footer();
  die;
}
```

Honestly, I think that is all you need to do.

However, if you need parts of the page to be editable you can register a post type such that it does not show up in the menus but is still accessible if you know the correct URL. These two arguments to `register_post_type` will do it:

```
'show_ui'            => true,
'show_in_menu'       => false,
```

You will need to create some kind of interface for associating the posts with your users (I think) and for accessing the edit screens.

Comment: Thanks s_ha_dum for your kind reply. The code you given is works to include the template but it override for all templates in site. So any page i open (including my home page) it shows this template. If you see my test server :http://test.omicron-it.com/wordpress-3.6.1/approved-data-table/ where you can click the title(board member) from table & it goes to my custom template page with an id & there showing some information's. Actually you got my point, i don't want to create page. I just want my template to display this information when click that title. That's all i need. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it would override all templates. It is just a sample, and one copied from another answer no less. It should be obvious how to modify your `content_template` function based on that model.

Comment: Yes.. i understand. But what is the best possible way to solve my issue ? Do you want me to post with a new topic ? Please i need a favor. Thanks & Regards.

Comment: If you need a plugin to handle this, then use this solution. @MarkKaplun suggested a shortcode or a child theme and I agree that that might be a better approach but I don't have all the information.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @s_ha_dum's answer, your basic problem is that you are trying to generate in a plugin presentation code, something that should be left to themes. whatever method you apply you will always be in risk that there will be a theme that behaves in a way you don't expect and your plugin will output a broken page.

If you need to be able to output only some content then your plugin should supply a shortcode. and if you truly need to have a full control over the design of a page then maybe creating a child theme will be better then a plugin.